# Tell me how to fix the application android

Tags: android, bluetooth

> I want to learn how to work with bluetooth. I can't start the simplest
> application. All the time, bluetooth output is not supported. How to
> fix that you could turn on bluetooth?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOn);
        Button buttonOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOff);
        BluetoothAdapter bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        //int  REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
        buttonOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(bAdapter == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    if(!bAdapter.isEnabled()){
                        Intent enableBt =  new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(enableBt, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth adapter On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        buttonOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth adapter Off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                bAdapter.disable();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Bluetooth disabled in the settings? If your device doesn't support Bluetooth, you can't use Bluetooth on that device. Sorry.

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If the device does not support bluetooth BluetoothAdapter will be null. [image]

And it seems you need to request permissions and you might need new [permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for Android 12.

```
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            ),
            BL_REQUEST_CODE
        )
```

Here is the answer that might help:
[Android 12 New Bluetooth Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722950/android-12-new-bluetooth-permissions)

Comment: I added the permission in manifest.xml. BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, BLUETOOTH.

Comment: It did not help!

Comment: I might need more information to help you, what device are you using? is it an emulator or a phone? and what version of Android is there?

Comment: Hello, Inliner. I am testing all programs in the emulator, version of android 8.0 Oreo, no errors. You need to try to test it on a real device. And another question about the variable REQUEST_ENABLE_BT, did I define it correctly?

Comment: Евгений, sorry for the delay, I just checked on my Moto X Play with Android 7 and Cube T10 with Android 6, and your code is working. You only need BLUETOOTH permission in manifest to turn bluetooth ON and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission to turn it OFF. For Android 12 you also need to request BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission and not just add it to manifest. Here it is explained more thorougly. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions

Comment: As for your error it might be device specific, so at least let us know what device you are using