# Bluetooth paired failure: 'Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for android.content.AttributionSource@11fa0bd1

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, android-12

I can't connect to the bluetooth in Android 12 devices. Its working fine with android 11 devices.
I have added all the permissions.

this is my AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ebsor_barcode">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer to your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69972855/8319640