# How can i add permission check in Android Studio?

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth, manifest

I am facing this issue after I debugged:

```
Process: com.example.testcode, PID: 9965
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity } from ProcessRecord{fa501bc 9965:com.example.testcode/u0a160} (pid=9965, uid=10160) requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
```

I added permissions to the manifest. The code is saying "add permission check" after adding permissions to the manifest.

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            //discovery cihaz buldugunda:
            if(action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)){
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch(state){
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG,"onReceive: STATE OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG,"onReceive: STATE TURNING OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG,"onReceive: STATE ON");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG,"onReceive: STATE TURNING ON");
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy: called.");
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnONOFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnONOFF);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        btnONOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onClick: enabling/disabling bluetooth.");
                enableDisableBT();
            }
        });

    }
    public void enableDisableBT(){
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){        //eğer cihazında bluetooth yoksa
            Log.d(TAG,"enableDisableBT: Does not have BT capabilities.");
        }
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){              //eğer cihazın bluetooth'u acık degilse
            Log.d(TAG,"enableDisableBT: enabling BT.");
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);   //bluetooth açılsın mı isteği..
            startActivity(enableBTIntent);  //neden CHECK istiyor ?
            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);    //IntentFilter ne yapıyor ?
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Log.d(TAG,"enableDisableBT: disabling BT.");
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }

    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

The set of permissions that you declare in your app depends on your app's target SDK version.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions

Maybe that answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/69972855/16711198