# Twilio video on android 12 crashes with missing BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission

Tags: android, twilio

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.abc.app, PID: 21262
java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for AttributionSource { uid = 10292, packageName = com.homemedics.app, attributionTag = null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@1342821, next = null }: HeadsetService
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2438)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2422)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2405)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2347)
at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothHeadset$Stub$Proxy.getConnectedDevicesWithAttribution(IBluetoothHeadset.java:1518)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothHeadset.java:682)
at com.twilio.audioswitch.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadsetManager.onServiceConnected(BluetoothHeadsetManager.kt:86)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadset$3.handleMessage(BluetoothHeadset.java:1640)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)

Comment: May be this thread will help you-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722950/android-12-new-bluetooth-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Update the twilio api for permission fix
//twilio
before (Bug)
implementation "com.twilio:audioswitch:1.1.0"
New (Fixed)
implementation "com.twilio:audioswitch:1.1.5"

Comment: that did the work for me, tks