# requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT

Tags: react-native

I'm facing this error for Android 12 or higher.

> BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission was also added in androidManifest.xml still error coming.

My current React Native version is 0.59.9.
I'm using third-party library to request Bluetooth permission(react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer)

```
Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE
cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity } from ProcessRecord{df6b879 25469:com.app/u0a151} (pid=25469, uid=10151) 
requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.app">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
 </manifest>
```

```
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 12.5
      CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M2
      Memory: 99.52 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 19.2.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
      npm: 8.19.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
      Watchman: 2022.11.14.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 22.1, iOS 16.1, macOS 13.0, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
      Xcode: 14.1/14B47b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: 0.59.9 => 0.59.9
```

Comment: which library do you use for BLUETOOTH?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 12 New Bluetooth Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722950/android-12-new-bluetooth-permissions)

Comment: i'm using react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer library for bluetooth permission