# Android app run time error and app crashes

Tags: java, android, debugging, bluetooth

I am following [this](https://github.com/clopresti/rpi-bluetooth/blob/master/Android/app/src/main/java/net/clopresti/rpibluetooth/MainActivity.java) code to control the LED on the Raspberry pi with an android application using bluetooth.

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722950/android-12-new-bluetooth-permissions.

Comment: It is in Kotlin, any resourse that helps how to implement it in java?

Comment: Well, it is straight forward, no need of difficult Java code. Just replace `val` with variable definition, add `;` at the end, etc.